# Qt, openCV and error code during run in debug mode windows 7

Tags: qt, opencv, windows-7

I have already install openCV and Qt framework on my windows 7 professiona 64.
I have add path with dynamic lib to system variable PATH.

```
Mat img_1 = imread( "pic.jpg" );
imshow( "Easy sample", img_1 );
waitKey(0);
```

When i try to compile this example from OpenCV page it compile with no error's and warnings but  it dosen't show any window with img.
When i try to run it in debug mode i get error code 0xc0000138.

I found that 0xc0000135 is missing dynamic lib file in system, but I can't find what mean 0xc0000138.

Comment: Not necesarily a solution, but a code without checks is dead. Write `Mat img_1 = imread(...); if(img_1.empty()) return -1;`

Answer (score 0):

i am also facing the same problem with opencv 2.4.0 and opencv 2.4.2...seems like imread is not working...

if you really need to work with image as Mat u can do the following....it works...

```
#include "iostream"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    IplImage *image = cvLoadImage("C:\\lena.jpg");
    Mat im(image);
    imshow("TEST",im);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: link the debug files...it will work...like opencv_core240d.lib..opencv_highgui240d.lib